# GNU make dependency issue

Tags: gnu-make

To make it simple, say I have the following folders:

- `./src/` with many .c files
- `./obj/` with many .obj files
- `./output/` with my binaries I want to build

My makefile is as follows:

```
all: init mybin

# init commands
init:
    mkdir obj
    mkdir output

mybin:  project1 project2 project3
    $(CC) src/misc.c ... etc
    $(LK) obj/first.obj obj/second.obj obj/third.obj obj/four.obj obj/five.obj obj/six.obj obj/seven.obj obj/eight.obj obj/nine.obj -o output/myapp.bin

project1: obj/first.obj obj/second.obj obj/third.obj

obj/first.obj: src/first.c
    $(CC) first.c ... etc

obj/second.obj: src/second.c
    $(CC) obj/second.c ... etc

obj/third.obj: src/third.c
    $(CC) obj/third.c ... etc


project2:   obj/four.obj obj/five.obj obj/six.obj

obj/four.obj: src/four.c
    $(CC) four.c ... etc

obj/five.obj: src/five.c
    $(CC) obj/five.c ... etc

obj/six.obj: src/six.c
    $(CC) obj/six.c ... etc


project3:   obj/seven.obj obj/eight.obj obj/nine.obj

obj/seven.obj: src/seven.c
    $(CC) seven.c ... etc

obj/eight.obj: src/eight.c
    $(CC) obj/eight.c ... etc

obj/nine.obj: src/nine.c
    $(CC) obj/nine.c ... etc
```

The first time I ran `make all`, everything compiled find. Then I did:

```
$ touch src/four.c
$ make all
$
```

But `make`  exits without compiling anything. I guess it did not detect that one of the .c files had changed, however I don't see what's wrong with my dependencies.

What I expected:
`touch`ing `src/four.c` should have marked `obj/four.obj` obsolete, and `project2` aswell, hence marking `mybin` obsolete too. This chain should trigger a new compilation of `src/four.c` to `obj/four.obj` and then a new linkage of the whole project.

Comment: run make -d all and see what's outdated

Comment: it's trying a LOT of "implicit prerequisite"s which have no meaning. I'm trying to build a file called `FW.mot` and `make` is trying to find `FW.mot.c` or `FW.mot.cc` or `FW.mot.F` which don't exist!!!

Comment: well, grep the relevant files, if it says FW.mot is up to date, then check all dependencies, if the one that should trigger the rebuild isn't there, then you haven't listed it in the Makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify the output file of compilation (likely the `-o` option)? By default (for most toolchains), compiling a `.c` file produces an `.o` file, not an `.obj` one.

### UPD.

To get Make updating targets when some prerequisites change you have to provide an **exact** dependencies **between files** as far as Make use timestamps to determine whether a file has been changed.

That is, `all` and `init` could remain as so-called [`.PHONY` targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets), but it is a good practice to make the rest targets to be files.

```
OUT_DIR := ./output
SRC_DIR := ./src
OBJ_DIR := ./obj

MYBIN := $(OUT_DIR)/myapp.bin

OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, \
    first.obj \
    second.obj \
    third.obj \
    four.obj \
    five.obj \
    six.obj \
    seven.obj \
    eight.obj \
    nine.obj)

.PHONY : all mkdir-output mkdir-obj
all : $(MYBIN)

mkdir-output :
    @mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)

mkdir-obj :
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

$(MYBIN) : $(OBJS) | mkdir-output
    $(LK) $^ -o $@

$(OBJS) : | mkdir-out
$(OBJS) : $(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $< -object=$@ $(CC_OPT)
```

The last rule is GNU Make's [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). And the `mkdir-xxx` prerequisites after a pipe sign `|` are [order-only](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) ones.

Comment: Yes I did. This is a proprietary C compiler for a specific HW. The command line is: `$(CC) ./src/whatever.c -object=./obj/whatever.obj $(CC_OPT)`. Every `$(CC)` command creates successfully its `.obj` file in the right folder. The problem is that `make` doesn't mark `.obj` files that depend on `touch`ed `.c` files as outdated.

Comment: Thank you. I was not making good use of `.PHONY` targets. I added some `@touch dummy_project1` to help `make` understand the build dependencies. I also cleaned up a bit, and now it's working fine. Thank you so much.